# Permissions on `/`

Tags: permissions, arch-linux

What should the permissions be for `/`? I ask because I completely removed all files from my drive and reinstalled the OS, but I still get "permission denied" errors for `/bin/zsh` when I try to log in as a non-root user. The only thing that is the same is the root of the drive. If that's the issue, I would like to not have to format and reinstall again to fix it. (any suggestions for that problem would be appreciated too.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
start cmd:> ls -ld /
drwxr-xr-x 30 root root 4096 27. Jun 21:36 /
```

Comment: yep... mine was rwxr--r--. Figures that I find this out *after* reinstalling.